# file returning null on reading

Tags: java, file-read

I have the following code:

```
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(textfilename);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
```

To read the text file, I pass the path of the text file through the textfilename variable. 
I have tried with 10 different files and only the file with a particular name returns null on reading the first line. Others can be easily read.

I cannot change the name of the file though.

What could be the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the contents of the file?  `readLine` returns `null` when it reaches the end of the file.

Comment: Does the file exist? Is the first line empty?

Comment: Could you please give us the filename of the file that isn't working (or the path) and some filenames of files that re working?

Comment: You need to add more information and more code, if not, it'll be hard to help you.

Comment: @JetStream The file is crit_IPDError.txt.

Comment: @EricGärtner the file does not contain an empty line. I verified that by viewing the contents of the file.

Comment: Can you provide the absolute path to crit_IPDError.txt ?

Comment: @Ouney E:\crit_IPDError.txt

Comment: Are other files which are working fine also reside in E drive?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this to see if `file` even exists or not aat the specified `path`:-

```
File file = new File(textfilename);
if(file.exists()){
FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath());
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
}
else 
System.out.println("File not present. Check name or path");
```

PS:- Also ensure that some content is there in the file or not.

Comment: That is not the problem, because in this case there will be a java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Comment: @pL4Gu33 true. Thanks for reminding.Added the check to be on safe side ;)

Comment: @AnkitNigam, the file has contents and can be viewed as well. Although, using the concept above, it still returns null.

Comment: @Vidya more can be said regarding this if you can provide that file also, else the above code should work most of the times.